# Is it possible to get the user object from the reset password page when using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to display the user's email in the reset password page, but I'm not sure if that object is accessible by default.

```
edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @token, email: @resource&.email)
```

I added the email param, and that works for users clicking on the link going forward, but already-sent emails with the reset password link won't have this param.

Comment: Do you understand that by doing that you are creating a potential security hole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `@token`, which is unique to each user. This means that you could find the user by their reset password token. There's many ways to do this, but assuming your model is a `User`, you can:

```
@token = params[:reset_password_token] # the token from the URL
@resource = User.find_by_reset_password_token(@token)
@email = @resource&.email
```